# Find number of occurrences of substring from a text field

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I have a database that unfortunately uses some `Text` datatype fields. I need to find the number of occurrences of a certain substring.

The following code works great to find occurrences from a `varchar` field, but fails at many steps for `text`:

```
SELECT
    KEY_FIELD,
    LEN(FIELD) - LEN(REPLACE(FIELD, 'findMe', ''))
FROM 
    TABLE
WHERE 
    FIELD LIKE '%findMe%';
```

`LEN()` does not work with `text`, and neither does `REPLACE()`.

`DATALENGTH()` does not work for this purpose as it is counting bytes and does not return a true representation of how many times the string occurs.

I have tried all combinations of `CAST()` and `CONVERT()` that I could think of, some of which fail to execute, while others execute but return wild numbers, like 67 where I expect a 1.

Is there a possible way to do this for a `Text` field?

My "best" attempt:

```
SELECT
    NAME,
    TEXT_FIELD,
    LEN(CONVERT(VARCHAR(max), TEXT_FIELD)) - LEN(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(max), TEXT_FIELD), 'view', ''))
FROM 
    TESTING
WHERE 
    TEXT_FIELD LIKE '%view%';'
```

I made a testing table for this question to demonstrate, and the above query returns:

```
NAME  | TEXT_FIELD                                                                  | COUNT
------|-----------------------------------------------------------------------------|------
NAME1 | There is a review in which we view the only views that a person could view. |16
NAME2 | Search me for the term view, it will also find review.                      |8
```

If you would like to try to reproduce:

```
CREATE TABLE TESTING(
    NAME varchar(50),
    TEXT_FIELD TEXT
);
INSERT INTO TESTING VALUES('NAME1', 'There is a review in which we view the only views that a person could view.');
INSERT INTO TESTING VALUES('NAME2', 'Search me for the term view, it will also find review.');
```

Comment: Casting/converting  to `varchar` *should* work. What DB do you use? Add your best attempt to use this approach to your question.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Updated to reflect Sql Server 2014

Comment: @PM77-1 I included my best attempt as well as a return from the attempt that includes sample data.

Answer (score 0):

Converting the `text` field to `varchar(max)` will make the functions work, but for each instance of the substring it will return the number of characters of the substring, so to get the correct number you need to divide by the length of the substring. (If anyone knows **why** this behavior happens from a converted `text` field but not a `varchar`, I would be interested to know)

Solution:

```
SELECT
    KEY_FIELD,
    TEXT_FIELD,
    (LEN(CONVERT(VARCHAR(max), TEXT_FIELD)) - LEN(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(max), TEXT_FIELD), 'substring', ''))) / LEN('substring') AS 'CountOfSubstring'
FROM 
    TABLE
WHERE 
    TEXT_FIELD LIKE '%substring%';'
```

Comment: From [`Replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#return-types): "If _string_expression_ is not of type **varchar(max)** or **nvarchar(max)**, **REPLACE** truncates the return value at 8,000 bytes. To return values greater than 8,000 bytes, _string_expression_ must be explicitly cast to a large-value data type."

Comment: From [`text`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/ntext-text-and-image-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15): "**IMPORTANT!** **ntext**, **text**, and **image** data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use **nvarchar(max)**, **varchar(max)**, and **varbinary(max)** instead."